# How to add RecylerView inside a ScrollView?

Tags: android

I want to add a RecylclerView inside a ScrollView. This is my code,

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">    

               <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view2"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"        
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

But when I run this code program terminates with the error

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

How to correct this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If RecyclerView gets put into a ScrollView, then during measure step its height is unspecified

You can fix some:

a specific height to RecyclerView

ScrollView.fillViewport to true

My opinion is to avoid scrollview having other scroll type view because you already have capabilties of scrolling in one view then why use another.

Comment: Yes this is the answer, there is the use case of wanting a horizontal list in a vertical recycler

Comment: you can also use recycler in your recycler item, list in your list item, as fits you, but these types of layouts are little bit complex.

Comment: This  works. But why it is not working with wrap_content as height parameter?